# nar-maven-plugin and native-library-loader dont load native lib

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, native

I testing with nar-maven-plugin, then in the next project I need JNI :( . I choosed the [it0003](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/it0003-jni) example from git repo. Without the native-library-loader, manual placing of the library and setting of library path its run. Then i would use the native-library-loader. For that, I added the dependency and the assembly-plugin for single JAR file. My current pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  #%L
  Native ARchive plugin for Maven
  %%
  Copyright (C) 2002 - 2014 NAR Maven Plugin developers.
  %%
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  #L%
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar.its.nar</groupId>
    <artifactId>it-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../it-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>it0003-jni</artifactId>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>

  <name>NAR JNI Test</name>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>
    Simple JNI Library
  </description>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org/</url>

  <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </properties>  

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <cpp>
            <debug>true</debug>
          </cpp>
          <c>
            <testOptions>
              <testOption>-DTESTOPT="this is a nar-testCompile flag"</testOption>
            </testOptions>
          </c>
          <libraries>
            <library>
              <type>jni</type>
              <narSystemPackage>it0003</narSystemPackage>
              <linkCPP>false</linkCPP>
            </library>
          </libraries>
          <javah>
            <includes>
              <include></include>
            </includes>
          </javah>
          <tests>
            <test>
              <name>HelloWorld</name>
            </test>
          </tests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>it0003.HelloWorldJNI</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scijava</groupId>
          <artifactId>native-lib-loader</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I placed the resulting JAR and the NAR in the same directory and starts with:

```
    rd4@PC222-VirtualBox ~/Schreibtisch/nartest $ java -Djava.library.path=/home/rd4/Schreibtisch/nartest/ -jar it0003-jni-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then i get following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Library 'libit0003-jni-1.0-SNAPSHOT.so' not found!
    at it0003.NarSystem.getLibPath(NarSystem.java:141)
    at it0003.NarSystem.loadLibrary(NarSystem.java:45)
    at it0003.HelloWorldJNI.<clinit>(HelloWorldJNI.java:27)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Library 'libit0003-jni-1.0-SNAPSHOT.so' not found!
    at it0003.NarSystem.getLibPath(NarSystem.java:141)
    at it0003.NarSystem.loadLibrary(NarSystem.java:45)
    at it0003.HelloWorldJNI.<clinit>(HelloWorldJNI.java:27)
```

Has anyone an idea what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue.

Make sure your $JAVA_HOME environment variable is set. On Linux, you can find this using `which java`, then exporting the path using `export <path>`.
Additionally, you should link to the include paths in the compiler options in your pom.xml file:

```
<c>
  <name>gcc</name>
  <exceptions>false</exceptions>
  <debug>false</debug>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.c</include>
  </includes>
  <options>
    <option>-I${java.home}/include</option>
    <option>-I${java.home}/include/linux</option>
  </options>
</c>

<linker>
  <name>gcc</name>
  <options>
    <option>-I${java.home}/include</option>
    <option>-I${java.home}/include/linux</option>
  </options>
</linker>
```

Hopefully this helps, pretty sure this was what fixed it. If I figure out what actually fixed it, I'll update this answer.